# Proof with Dirac delta function

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, dirac-delta

I have to prove that Dirac delta function $\delta$ is equal to this limit:

$$ \delta(x) = \lim_{a\to \infty}\frac{sin(ax)}{\pi x}.$$

We can say, show that the result of the right side of equality is defined as Dirac function:

$$ \delta(x) = \begin{cases}
+\infty,  & x=0, \\
0, & x\neq0.
\end{cases} $$

Thank you for help.

Comment: I'm confused: $\frac{\sin(ax)}{ \pi x }\leq \frac{1}{\pi x} < 1$ for every $x > 1/\pi$

Comment: There's something wrong with this statement, as the limit does not exist for most $x$ (and is not even defined at $x=0$). In any case, I think you meant $0$ if $x \neq 0$ and $+\infty$ otherwise, although I still find this definition quite problematic: what is the difference between $\delta$ and $2\delta$?

Comment: I am confused too, when I used l'Hopital rule for limits, the limit change to $ \lim_{a\to \infty}\frac{cos(ax)}{\pi}.$ I think, this limit is undefined, because cosinus oscillates between -1 and 1 in infinity. Is it possible to prove?

Comment: @PedroM.: The statement is correct. It needs to be interpreted as a generalized limit, i.e. $\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{\pi x}\phi(x)dx=\phi(0)$ for some test function $\phi(x)$.

Comment: @MrPitivier You can't use L'Hôpital, as the numerator does not approach infinity.

Comment: @MattL. Got it. It sounds like the OP is currently taking a course that may be too advanced for him at this stage.

Comment: @PedroM. Yeah, definitely, obviously you are so genius, that you solved this...everybody can make mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought my comment was offensive, but all I meant is that it looks like whichever course you're taking is discussing some topics on "Theory of Distributions", which may be too advanced at this stage. For instance, you need to understand that $\delta$ is defined as a distribution (via an integral formula) rather than as a function, and so your original limit is a generalized limit rather than a regular limit (see @MattL.'s comment).